# Android translate animation from view

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I implement appearance one view from another?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use the translate animation class

```
View view1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.view_id);

     //defining an animation to scroll the view and the direction
        TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(view1.getX(),180,0,0);
      // time it will take to finish reach destination, this means how fast the view will translate
        mAnimation.setDuration(1000); 
       // repetition 
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.ABSOLUTE);
        view.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

the `TranslateAnimation(value1, value2, value3, value4)` indicate the starting co-ordinate and the ending co-ordinate of the view. it also implies the direction of translation. `view1.getX()` will get the current position.

If you don't want to use Translate class then you can update the position of the time at regular interval. probably every one-sec.
you can use this code

```
View view = new View(this);
    while(true){
        sleep(1000);
        view.setX(view.getX() + 1);

        // define a condition to stop;

    }
```

The view.getX() will return the current position of the view then increase it by a value at regular interval(1 sec), each  time the line execute it get the current location and increase it. this should be be done in a thread because the UI thread may not be able to handle it effectively.

Comment: in your case, view2 will be show before and after view1, but I need only after

Comment: place the two view on top of  each other, just start translation from the cuurent position, it does not necessary have to start from the left edge, it can start from any where. that's why you have the `(value1, value2, value3, value4)` parameter

Comment: view2 is bigger than view1, that's why if I start traslation from view1 then part of view2 will be seen from the left side of view1

Comment: have updated my code and also added another method. as for the view2 showing behind view1, just make the second view invisible for one or two sec(s)

Comment: If I make second view invisible for a few seconds then translation start not from begining right side of view1